# Excel - Loop Through Formatting Copy & Paste

Tags: excel, for-loop, conditional-formatting

I am essentially trying to take the formatting from my Column(A) Row(3) and copy its formating and paste the Formatting to the Row Below it. Is there a better way to write my loop?

```
Sub Copy_Formatting()

  Dim rNum As Long

  For rNum = 3 To 26

     If Range("A" & rNum) <> "" Then

        Range(("A" & rNum), ("B" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("A" & rNum + 1), ("B" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("C" & rNum), ("D" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("C" & rNum + 1), ("D" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("E" & rNum), ("F" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("E" & rNum + 1), ("F" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("G" & rNum), ("H" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("G" & rNum + 1), ("H" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("I" & rNum), ("J" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("I" & rNum + 1), ("J" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("K" & rNum), ("L" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("K" & rNum + 1), ("L" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("M" & rNum), ("N" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("M" & rNum + 1), ("N" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("O" & rNum), ("P" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("O" & rNum + 1), ("P" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("Q" & rNum), ("R" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("Q" & rNum + 1), ("R" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("S" & rNum), ("T" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("S" & rNum + 1), ("T" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("U" & rNum), ("V" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("U" & rNum + 1), ("V" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("W" & rNum), ("X" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("W" & rNum + 1), ("X" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("Y" & rNum), ("Z" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("Y" & rNum + 1), ("Z" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("AA" & rNum), ("AB" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("AA" & rNum + 1), ("AB" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("AC" & rNum), ("AD" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("AC" & rNum + 1), ("AD" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("AE" & rNum), ("AF" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("AE" & rNum + 1), ("AF" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range(("AG" & rNum), ("AH" & rNum)).Copy
        Range(("AG" & rNum + 1), ("AH" & rNum + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Range("AI" & rNum).Copy
        Range("AI" & rNum + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

     Else: Exit Sub
     End If

  Next rNum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a loop ... just do it at once:

```
Sub test()
   Rows("3:3").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Rows("4:26").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

a) select the source row - ENTIRE row, not just 1 cell at a time.

b) copy the source row (do this once, no need to do it repeatedly).

c) past the formatting (only) to ALL the target rows ... one operation ...

Comment: I like this approach very much but what If this was a dynamic event (meaning that all my target rows will be constantly changing). I would need it to select the last row with data. off the top of your head do you have a quick fix for that?

Comment: @evolancer: how are you doing it now ? It's no different than whatever method you would use in your original solution ;) Search around for "select last row of data in excel" and you'll find a variety of methods for doing that.

Comment: The problem I am having referencing the Rows(rNum:rNum)  <--- I get an error?? and looping through that while incrementing it. 

Sub Test()

    Dim rNumn As Long
    
For rNum = 3 To 10000
    
    If Range("A" & rNum) <> "" Then

   Rows("3:3").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Rows(rNum:rNum).Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
       
            Else: Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
 
Next rNum

End Sub

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you try going into the immediate window and type: `? rows("3:3").select`  ??

Comment: I figured out the problem thank you for the help Ditto is there a way I can give you reputation points or anything or upvote this to help you out?

Comment: *shrug* you marked answer correct, upvote what you feel is worth it :) I'm not here for points, don't really care for points ;)  heh  Just glad to help